# Include path (pwd) in bash history command

Tags: bash, terminal

I think it would be useful to show where the command was executed when running the `history` command on terminal.
I was able to include the datetime using:

```
$ echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

I tried using `HISTTIMEFORMAT="${pwd} - %d/%m/%y %T "` but it didn't work. I believe it only expects time syntax. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried using `HISTTIMEFORMAT="${pwd} ..."` but it didn't work.

This is because `HISTTIMEFORMAT` only controls how the `history` command *displays* dates, and not how dates are *stored*. Inside the file `.bash_history`, the dates are always stored in Unix time. `history` loads this information and formats it using `HISTTIMEFORMAT`. Since the loaded information never contained the working directory, there is no chance to print it later. Therefore, we have to modify the history when it is updated.

I don't think the additional information can be reliable stored like the timestamps without modifying bash's source code. I tried it for hours.

You could add additional history entries using `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -v "cd $(printf %q "$PWD")"'` or you could decorate the existing entries with a comment `# ran in ...`. I tried both, but found it very annoying, as you have to deal with the additional/modified history entries in your terminal session.

Therefore, keeping an additional history file seems to be the better option. For some examples on how to do this, see

- [How to log all Bash commands by all users on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/q/93566/606503)
- [How can I fully log all bash scripts actions?](https://serverfault.com/q/103501/411978)
- [How can you log every command typed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86000/187122)

With most solutions, you just have to add a `$(pwd)` somewhere in the logged string, so that the working directory is logged to.

Answer (score 0):

bash historu is stored under

```
~/.bash_history
```

and if you look into it clearly it does not have root path or something.

You can only get timestamp and executed command.

regards

Comment: Yes, I understand that `~/.bash_history` does not includes the path. It also did not include the timestamp by default but I was able to get it with `HISTTIMEFORMAT`. I was hopping that there was another variable I could use to customize history exit. Thank you.

Comment: It does include timestamp starting with `#`